# How to Hide receiver email from To Field in Outlook

Tags: outlook

I am new to Outlook and I want to know how to hide all receivers in To field in Outlook so that receiver don't get an idea of other receivers.

Answer (score 0):

Please go throught below link. This might help you.

https://www.howtogeek.com/185233/how-to-hide-email-addresses-when-sending-to-multiple-recipients-in-outlook-2013/

Answer (score 0):

That is what BCC is for - recipients never see it. Or you can send the message to each recipient separately.